# Why image as plane not giving transparent result

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, add-on, image, transparency

I want to add a decal to my model. With the image as plane addon. Imported image as plane and added subdivision modifier and shrink wrap modifier. Why its giving black shade or color, The image is transparent and the node are default from image as plane addon. Rendering in Cycles.

[image]

Any suggestion whats going wrong, why im not getting transparent decal. Thanks

Comment: it may be a problem of overlapping faces, using a Shrinkwrap is probably not a good idea, if you want to stick a decal, do it in the material

Comment: @moonboots how to do it in material?

Comment: you need to find a tutorial that will explain, for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPbAIf5HbJI

Comment: one way to avoid this is to go to the shrinkwrap modifier and set _Offset_ to a very small value, so that the decal is barely above the surface of the object.